# Beamer: Line spread in headline is ignored

Tags: beamer, titles, line-spacing

I am trying to build my own beamertheme and I want to modify the line spread in the title.

I use  `{\LARGE \linespread{1.6} \selectfont \inserttitle \par}` to modify the line spread, but it does only work in the main text of a frame and not inside the headline.

My minimal theme looks like this

```
\ProvidesPackage{beamerthememinimum}

\mode<presentation>

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{  
    {\LARGE \linespread{1.6} \selectfont \inserttitle \par}
}
```

and my test presentation looks like this:

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
  \mode<presentation> { 
    \usetheme{minimum}    
  }
  \usepackage[english]{babel}

 \title{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. }
  \begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{} 
    \vfill
    \begin{block}{\large Test}
      {\Large \linespread{1.6} \selectfont \inserttitle \par}
    \end{block}
    \vfill
  \end{frame}
  \end{document}
```

Here is a picture of the compiled output:

[image: Compiled output]

As you can see, the text inside the frame is correctly spaced, but the line spread command in the headline does not affect the spacing of the title output.

How can I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`beamer` explicitly turns off linespacing in the headline.

If you add this to your beamer theme (with the `%` before `\offinterlineskip` being the only change) then line spacing works again. But something else may break:-)

```
\def\beamer@typesetheadorfoot#1{% typeset the head or footline
  {\parskip0pt %\offinterlineskip%
    \hbox{%
      \hskip-\Gm@lmargin%
      \hbox{%
        \vbox{%
          \@tempdima=\textwidth%
          \textwidth=\paperwidth%
          \hsize=\textwidth%
          \def\\{,}%
          \usebeamertemplate***{#1}%
        }}%
      \hskip-\Gm@rmargin%
    }}\hfil%
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked like a charm. And it does not seem to break anything at first glance. :)