# Use a specific linespread in beamer but only for one frame

Tags: beamer

How can I change the

```
\linespread
```

for a specified frame only and not for the entire document?

Comment: Hi, have you seen the link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66199/beamer-line-spread-in-headline-is-ignored?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply change it inside the frame and the change will be local.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\lipsum[2]
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\linespread{1.5}\selectfont
\lipsum[2]
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\lipsum[2]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Again +1. Good and fine work.

Comment: Why do we need the `\selectfont` at the end? Without that, it is not working.